# Why do two inline-block spans not just appear next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I have these two spans I would like to render: First a dot, then some text.

```html
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #bcbcbc" />
<span style="display: inline-block;">Some text</span>
```

But all I get this:

[image]

I'm sorry.. It's late and I just don't get it...

Comment: You have nested your spans. Spans cannot be self-closed.

Comment: Why not you use one span only with ::before pseudo selector? Using this, you can create a dot or anything before the text and they will align in a same line.

Comment: I can't just use a span, make it an inline-block element and give it a width and height with no text?

Comment: You need a container block with display style such grid, table, etc. see about it in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) site.

Comment: @Lenn Did you get the one span with ::before pseudo element approach?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `<span... />` use `<span>...</span>`